# How to make a backup of an Oracle database that does not mess up the regular backup cycle?

Tags: oracle, migration, oracle-11g, rman

**Goal**

I want to move a database from server A to server B. Both server have the same technology so one way is to shutdown the source database, copy data files,control file, redo logs, parameter file  to from A to B and start the database on B. But this will take to long so I will use a method that involves the archive logs. For example I can use dataguard an build a standby on SERVER B and switch to this standby during migration. But for some reasons I don't want to use a standby nor can I access the backup of the A database to restore it on B.

**Method**

Before RMAN I did this the following way:

1. Set the database of A in backup mode and copy all data files to a disk attached to the server and unset the backup mode.
2. Move this  disk to B and attache it to it.
3. Now from time to time archives are transported to B and applied
4. During the migration the last archives are brought to B and applied and the database is copied.

Of course I can try this with RMAN, too. And instead copying all the archives I can use incremental backups too.

So I do the following:

1. Make a level 0 backup to a disk attached to server A.
2. Move the disk to B and restore the database on Server B.
3. Now from time to time archives are transported to B and applied
4. During the migration the last archives are brought to B and applied and the database is copied.

I even could apply incremental backup instead of archives except for the last phase but here I am not interested in that.

**Problem**

My problem is now that the database on A is backed up using incremental backups:
1. On Sunday a level 0 backup is taken
2. on the remaining 6 days a level 1 backup is taken

I want to to copy my level 0 backup for migration on Wednesday. But this messes up the regular backup. Assume I do this level 0 backup on Wednesday morning then the nightly level 1 backup on Wednesday 
refers to the level 0 backup on this morning and not to the level 1 backup of the previous day as usual. But in case of a restore/recovery Thursday we have a problem, because the disk 
of the Wednesday level 0 backup is not available anymore. I think the database can be still recovered because the missing time interval can be recovered with archive logs.
But I want a solution that does not mess up the regular backup. So the level 1 backup On Wednesday  should refer to the level 1 backup on Tuesday.

**Solutions**

How can I achieve this?

At the moment I see the following way:

I use duplicate from active database to make a copy of the database on A to the disk attached to A. This database must not be opened so that I can recover it with archive logs later. This disk is detached from A and moved to B. Here the datafiles are registered as datafile copies and restored to th server B.

But this needs an additional instance on A so that I can duplicate to this instance.

Another way may be

```
 BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1... FOR RECOVER OF COPY WITH TAG...
```

as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/bkup004.htm)

The manual says:

> The `BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1... FOR RECOVER OF COPY WITH TAG...` command does not actually always create a level 1 incremental backup. 
>   If there is no level 0 image copy backup of an particular data file, then executing this command creates an 
>   image copy backup of the data file on disk with the specified tag instead of creating the level 1 backup.
>
> Each time a data file is added to the database, an image copy of the new data file is created the next time the script runs. 
>   The time after that, the first level 1 incremental for that data file is created, and on all subsequent runs the new data file 
>   is processed like any other data file.
>
> Tags must be used to identify the incremental level 0 data file copies created for use in this strategy, 
>   so that they do not interfere with other backup strategies you implement. If you have multiple incremental 
>   backup strategies in effect, RMAN cannot unambiguously create incremental level 1 backups unless you tag level 0 backups.

This sounds good but I actually have to test this.

**My question**

*What method do you propose to get a level 0 online backup that is ignored by the following level 0 backup of the regular backup cycle?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FULL-Backup does not interfere with the regular backup.

From the description of the `BACKUP` command in the ["Database Backup and Recovery Reference" of "Oracle Database Online Documentation 11g Release 2 (11.2)"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta007.htm#RCMRF107) for the backup operand FULL:

> Creates a backup of all blocks of data files included in the backup. `FULL` is the opposite of `INCREMENTAL`. RMAN makes full backups by default if neither `FULL` nor `INCREMENTAL` is specified.
>   A full backup has no effect on subsequent incremental backups and is not considered a part of any incremental backup strategy. A full image copy backup can be incrementally updated, however, by applying incremental backups with the `RECOVER` command.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use RMAN to `DUPLICATE DATABASE TO OTHERDB`.  Feel free to use one of the related methods that fits your environment/requirements.

References:

- https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmdupdb.htm#BRADV010

Comment: Thank you for your input. I already mentioned the duplicate method as one of my solutions (I added more details now to make this more clear). Your first link starts with `BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG`. Does this backup interfere with the regular backup (like a level 0 backup as I suspect)  or is it ignored by the level 1 backups?

Comment: I looked up the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta007.htm#RCMRF107) and it says "A full backup has no effect on subsequent incremental backups and is not considered a part of any incremental backup strategy. A full image copy backup can be incrementally updated, however, by applying incremental backups with the RECOVER command.A full backup has no effect on subsequent incremental backups and is not considered a part of any incremental backup strategy. A full image copy backup can be incrementally updated, ...." a FULL backup was what I was looking for.

Comment: I  upvoted your answer but I didn't accept it because it did not contain the relevant details, I posted this in my own answer.